# ASP.NET MVC C# OWIN token authentication with social logins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt, owin

I am after some guidance.  I have set-up my ASP.NET C# OWIN MVC application to authenticate using JWT tokens.  I used the `IAppBuilder` extension `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` to create an endpoint for issuing tokens to users.  Everything works correctly - when a correct username and password combination is posted to this endpoint a local JWT token is generated and returned to the client.

I now want to extend this functionality to social account logins.  I want my users to be able to authenticate using Facebook and to issue a local JWT token for them once they are successfully returned from the Facebook authentication.  I can't use the endpoint being used for local accounts because it requires a username/password combination post - which I don't have for users who have authenticated using Facebook.  So, my essential question is - how do I generate a local JWT token for users authenticated using external social logins?